# How to show alert from separate code module in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

How do you show an alert from a separate code moduel in asp.net, not the codebehind of a page, thats an easy one.

This is one way to do it from the code behind of a page.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "alert('Hello')", True)
```

How can i achieve this from a separate code module though, i am not sure. it needs a control and control type for the first to parameteres respectively. So the code above will error out on the first 2 params. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Page object of the current request to this extern module. Then you can use it in the `RegisterStartupScript` function. For example:

Some extern class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Shared Sub DoSomething(Page As Page)
        ' do something
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "alert('Hello');", True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the`aspx` page or CodeBehind:

```
' ...
MyClass.DoSomething(Page)
' ...
```